# Download multiple files in C# (one at a time only / queue)

Tags: c#, windows, file, download

I'm writing an updater in C# and I need some help now (I'm new to this language, please explain your tips :D )

My Code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("tmp");
            int mmx = updnec.Count();
            label6.Text = "0/" + mmx;
            MessageBox.Show(label6.Text);
            int mmn = 0;
            foreach (string lz in link)
            {

                    MessageBox.Show(lz);
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(lz), "tmp/update00" + mmn + ".exe");
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                    label6.Text = mmn + "/" + mmx;
                    mmn = +1;
                    //Whithout that while{} - part, it tries to download all links from the list at once. But I don't want the program to do that. I don't want it to show a message all the time, too, but when i leave that while{} - part empty, the program just freezes and doesn't even download. 
while (progressBar1.Maximum != progressBar1.Value)

                        {
                        MessageBox.Show("Test");
                    }

            }



        }
        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive;
            progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived;
            string sysload = progressBar1.Value /1000000 + "/" + progressBar1.Maximum /1000000 + " MB geladen";
            label12.Text = sysload;
        }
```

Read the comment int my code please.

How to solve my problem!? Please help me!

Reditec

Edit:

```
label11.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(link);



        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> lz = (List<string>)e.Argument; 


            int mmn = 0;    

            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("tmp");
            int mmx = 10;
            label6.Text = "0/" + mmx;
            foreach (string lkz in lz)
                using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hallo" + lkz);
                client.DownloadFile(lkz, "tmp/update00" + mmn + ".exe");
            } 


        }
```

Comment: What you can do is to zip the files into one zip file and send the zip file to the client.  I dont think there is another way to do that. Check below link for more information

Comment: Why don't you include a question instead of an instruction to read comments? Questions seeking debugging help must include a specific problem in the question itself.

Comment: @MoezRebai That's not possible for me :D

Comment: @Sayse To SHOW you my PROBLEM.

Comment: @Sayse In the Comment section (the "//" part) is my question. Quote: Whithout that while{} - part, it tries to download all links from the list at once. But I don't want the program to do that. I don't want it to show a message all the time, too, but when i leave that while{} - part empty, the program just freezes and doesn't even download.

Comment: clarify, please - do you want do download your files one-by-one, not all at once, is it your problem?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I want to download the files one-by-one (when the one before is finished), not all at once!

Comment: Quote from [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Help others reproduce the problem
Not all questions benefit from including code....it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem.". Quote from close reason: "questions seeking debugging help must include ..a specific problem.. **in the question itself**. Either way, your solution is not to use `async`

Comment: @Sayse Thank you for informing me about that rule :)

Comment: @Sayse Without Async, my progressbar doesnt work :D How to fix that? :)

Comment: You should use a background worker (or other threading resources) to do the entire downloading task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use a BackgroundWorker and download your files in sync instead of async.
You can find an example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Here is an example:

```
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{ 
   var links = new[] { "link1", "link2" }; 

   var percentProgressStep = (100 / links.Length) + 1

   using (var client = new WebClient()) 
   foreach (string l in links) 
     {
       client.DownloadFile(l, Path.GetTempFileName());
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentProgressStep);
     } 
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. Thans for your answer :)

Comment: what do you mean with downloading the files in sync? :O

Comment: Use DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync, BackgroundWorker already do work in async (without block your form) for you.

Comment: would you please show me what you mean, with a piece of code? :)

Comment: void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var links = new[] { "link1", "link2" };

            using (var client = new WebClient())
                foreach (string l in links)
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(l, Path.GetTempFileName());
                }
        }

Comment: would you please edit my code and put it on a websit (this for example http://collabedit.com/ynudk) and send me the link? :)

Comment: I can't, I provide to you all the keys to achieve what you want to do, just mix my code with the example provided in the link and it will work fine.